Show that a subvariety of the projective space with degree 1 is linear
I want to prove that given $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ closed irreducible with degree 1 is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$. I have this answer, but treats only the case $\dim(X)=1$.
I'm trying to generalize that answer in different ways (e.g. induction) but it doesn't seem to work. Another approach is:
If $\dim(X)=0$ then $X$ is a point then is linear. Suppose $\dim(X)\geq1$, say  $d$, then given $d$-points in $X$ and $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ linear of dimension $n-d$ that contains the given points we have
$$\dim(X\cap\Lambda)\geq \dim(X)+\dim(\Lambda)-n= 0.$$ But we also have $|X\cap\Lambda|\geq d\gneq\operatorname{deg}(X)=1$ and so
$\dim(X\cap\Lambda)\geq 1$. But now I don't know how to conclude.
Any help? Thanks.

What exactly do "closed irreducible with degree 1" mean? I guess it boils down to be the solution to a single linear equation, which is clearly a linear subspace

I think this is essentially covered by the answer at this question. Do you agree? (One way which this may not work is if you're not using schemes - I'd probably have to slightly adjust the answer for classical varieties, but it could be done.)

@GiuseppeNegro: It means that $X$ is a projective variety and the degree is just the maximum finite intersection points with a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n-\text{dim}(X)$.

@KReiser: Yes unfortunately I’am not using schemes.

@KReiser: Do you have any reference for the proof you linked but with variety language?

Yes, see the answer below. Also, you had some strange formatting and a typo or two in your post, I cleaned those up for you. (See especially $\dim$ for $\dim$, which looks much better than how you were previously doing it.)

@Radagast is there a reason you accepted the answer but did not upvote it? If something's missing, I'd like to fix it.

@KReiser: The reason is that I was trying to prove the result without invoking Bezout, but trying to generalize the linked proof, and this explains my approach in the question. Nevertheless, your answer proved what I wanted and that’s why I accepted it.

Also, I did not specify in my question that I didn’t want to use Bezout, so it was incorrect not to accept your answer.

Proposition 18.10 in Harris' Algebraic Geometry, a first course proves using the language of varieties the claim proven here in the language of schemes:

Proposition 18.10. Let $X\subset\Bbb P^n$ be an irreducible nondegenerate variety of dimension $k\geq 1$, and let $Y=X\cap H\subset H\cong\Bbb P^{n-1}$ be a general hyperplane section of $X$. Then $Y$ is nondegenerate in $\Bbb P^{n-1}$, and if $k\geq 2$ then $Y$ is irreducible as well.
Proof. To begin, the nondegeneracy statement is relatively elementary; we will prove it for any $H$ intersecting $X$ generically transversely. Suppose that $Y$ is contained in a subspace $\Lambda\cong\Bbb P^{n-2}$, and let $\{H_\lambda\}$ be the family of hyperplanes in $\Bbb P^n$ containing $\Lambda$. Since $X$ is not contained in any finite union of hyperplanes, it will intersect a general member $H_\lambda$ of this pencil in at least one point $p$ not lying on $Y$; the point $p$ will lie on an irreducible component $Z_\lambda$ of $X\cap H_\lambda$ not contained in $Y$. By Bezout, then, we will have $$\deg(X\cap H_\lambda)\geq \deg(Y) + \deg(Z_\lambda) > \deg(Y) = d,$$ a contradiction.

The proof continues with the irreducibility of $Y$. We don't need to do that for this specific application, since by the generalized Bezout theorem (i.e. $\sum_{Z\subset H\cap X \text{ irreducible}} i(X,H,Z)\deg Z = (\deg X)(\deg H)$) any intersection of a hyperplane and an irreducible closed subset of degree one will be generically transverse and irreducible.
